# Printing how many times a word occurs in a string

Tags: string

I'm trying to print how many times a word occurs in a string, this is my code:

```
count = 0
wordfreq = 0

sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
word = input("Enter a word within the setence: ")

sentence2 = sentence.split()

wordcount = [sentence2.count.(word) for word in sentence2]

print (wordcount)
```

However, when I run the program and enter the word that I'd wish for it to calculate how many times it occurs, the code returns it in the format of how many times it was stated like, as well as the number of times.

For example, if I had "This is a sentence, I like to write a sentence]

And the word I wanted to choose was "a", it would return [2, 2], whereas I would want it just to return [2].

Comment: It helps if you tag the question with the used language.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Python 3.
It looks like your code is over complicated. `wordcount = [sentence2.count.(word) for word in sentence2]` only needs to be `wordcount = sentence2.count.(word)`

And if you want to find a set of characters in a string...

```
count = 0

sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
word = input("Enter a word within the setence: ")

sentence2 = list(sentence)
word2 = list(word)

for i in range(0, len(sentence2)-len(word2)+1):
    trying = sentence2[i:len(word2)+i]
    if trying == word2:
        count+=1

print (count)
```

This code basically does that.